# How does the ISP resolve or determine the root servers for a particular Zone?

Tags: dns, bind

Let us say I am trying to find out the delegated subdomains for superuser.com

When I perform dig +trace, I get this result:

```
dig +trace superuser.com A

; <<>> DiG 9.2.1 <<>> +trace superuser.com A
;; global options:  printcmd
.                       6245    IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       6245    IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
;; Received 505 bytes from x.x.x.x#53(x.x.x.x) in 1 ms

com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 491 bytes from 192.x.x.x#53(g.root-servers.net) in 231 ms

superuser.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-245.awsdns-30.com.
superuser.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-1699.awsdns-20.co.uk.
superuser.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
superuser.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
;; Received 269 bytes from 192.y.y.y#53(e.gtld-servers.net) in 137 ms

superuser.com.          300     IN      A       151.x.x.x
superuser.com.          300     IN      A       151.y.z.a
superuser.com.          300     IN      A       151.y.1.a
superuser.com.          300     IN      A       151.y.z.b
superuser.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-1699.awsdns-20.co.uk.
superuser.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-245.awsdns-30.com.
superuser.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
superuser.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
;; Received 229 bytes from 205.z.z.z#53(ns-245.awsdns-30.com) in 15 ms

l.gtld-servers.net
e.gtld-servers.net
b.gtld-servers.net
```

How does the ISP Resolve which root servers need to be queried to? Here it picked g.root-servers.net. Is this random? Is the similar Logic applied to genericTLDs too?

Comment: This question has a pretty in-depth answer regarding this general topic - - https://superuser.com/q/527116/302907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All authoritative servers for the same zone **have the same contents**. So you don't need to determine anything; you can just pick one NS record and go with it.

(Don't think of the root or TLD zones as special. They're ordinary zones with ordinary NS records, and their authoritative servers work the same way. The root zone [looks like this.](https://www.internic.net/domain/root.zone))

Therefore it doesn't matter if you ask the A-root, or the G-root, or the L-root: if the question was "who's authoritative for the `com.` zone", **all of them** will give you the correct answer.

---

(Though, as you can see from [the other thread](https://superuser.com/a/543734/302907) which @Anakasunaman linked to, many recursive resolvers will eventually settle on the "fastest" server – however, that's purely for performance reasons and does not affect the final result. One-shot tools like `dig` don't bother with this.)